# Index or size was negative, or greater than the allowed value.

Tags: javascript, jquery, error-handling, console

I'm using color-thief.js on my website to render a colorpalette based on my portfolio image.

Sometimes it's working but I'm getting the error below most of the time. I'm no JS superhero so it would be really nice if somebody could help me out here.

> Uncaught IndexSizeError: Index or size was negative, or greater than
>   the allowed value.

[Link to my portfolio page](http://www.ravenwebdesign.nl/portfolio/duiksport/)

You can see the error pop up in the console and it seems to do be fine when I load it for the first time in a small while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That behavior (sometimes it works, sometimes not) is caused by trying to invoke color thief without image being loaded, try to use onload event:

```
var el = document.getElementById(my_image_id);
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
  var dominantColor = colorThief.getColor(el);
  /* ... */
};
img.src = el.getAttribute('src');
```